# Selenium WebDriver: Function is not breaking out of loop when two values on the same row are found

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My function iterates through the table two times to find the two input values that exists on the same row. But it is not breaking out of the loop when rowNo2 and rowNo are equal. What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks!

```
            WebElement table = oWebDriver.getWebElement(tableObject);
            List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
            List<WebElement> cols = table.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            int colSize = (cols.size()) / (rows.size());
            int rowNo = 0;
            int rowNo2 = 0;
            int colNo = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < cols.size(); i++) {

                System.out.println("row No2 = " + rowNo2);
                System.out.println("row No1 = " + rowNo);

                WebElement cellData = cols.get(i);
                if (cellData.getText().contains(rowData)||cellData.getText().contains(rowData.toUpperCase())) {
                    int l = i / colSize;
                    rowNo = l + 1;
                    for (int k = 0; k < cols.size(); k++) {
                        WebElement cellData2 = cols.get(k);
                        if (cellData2.getText().contains(rowData2)||cellData2.getText().contains(rowData2.toUpperCase())) {
                            int n = k / colSize;
                            rowNo2 = n + 1;
                            if (rowNo2 == rowNo) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just stopping the inner loop but not an outer one, to stop the outer loop execution also you need to put one more condition.

There are many ways you can break an outer loop but here is the simple one, add `i = cols.size();` line after the inner loop `if` condition :

```
if (rowNo2 == rowNo) {
    i = cols.size();
    break;
}
```

Which will stops an outer loop execution as well once `rowNo2 == rowNo` satisfied.

Comment: If I put the if statement in the outer loop. Won't it stop on the first iteration? since rowNo2 and rowNo are both 0 at the start.

Comment: Yes, it will stop if they both are equal at same index otherwise you need to include inner loop also I guess. Please accept and up vote my answer if its helpful, thank you.

Comment: @user11045740, just for the confirmation, is it breaking the loop now as per your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of labelled break in Java. May be you can try something like this -

```
WebElement table = oWebDriver.getWebElement(tableObject);
        List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        List<WebElement> cols = table.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        int colSize = (cols.size()) / (rows.size());
        int rowNo = 0;
        int rowNo2 = 0;
        int colNo = 0;

        here:for (int i = 0; i < cols.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println("row No2 = " + rowNo2);
            System.out.println("row No1 = " + rowNo);

            WebElement cellData = cols.get(i);
            if (cellData.getText().contains(rowData)||cellData.getText().contains(rowData.toUpperCase())) {
                int l = i / colSize;
                rowNo = l + 1;
                for (int k = 0; k < cols.size(); k++) {
                    WebElement cellData2 = cols.get(k);
                    if (cellData2.getText().contains(rowData2)||cellData2.getText().contains(rowData2.toUpperCase())) {
                        int n = k / colSize;
                        rowNo2 = n + 1;
                        if (rowNo2 == rowNo) {
                            break here;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: 'here' acts as a label for the outer for loop. So as soon as rowNo2 equals rowNo, it will immediately break the outer loop and the execution starts from the next subsequent lines of code